# rails 5 validators not protecting against a missing attribute during Model create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

cannot seem to get my validators to work to ensure all attributes are present to allow a User to be created. Basic User with 2 attributes

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
        validates :name, presence: true
        validates :email, presence: true
    end
```

tests to check that name and email are present when created. these #pass

```
    RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
        context 'validations' do
          subject { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }
          it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:email) }
          it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:name) }
          it "fails to create user unless both are present" do
            expect { User.create(:name => 'jo bloggs1', :noemail => 'c@c.co')}.to raise_error(ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError)
          end
        end
    end
```

but if i try and create model with a missing attribute no error is raised

```
 it "fails to create user unless both are present" do
    expect { User.create(:name => 'jo bloggs1')}.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError)
  end
```

**result**

```
  1) User validations fails to create user unless both are present
     Failure/Error: expect { User.create(:name => 'jo bloggs1')}.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError)
       expected ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError but nothing was raised
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

fyi, FactoryGirl

```
              FactoryGirl.define do
          factory :user do
            name "MyString"
            email "MyString"
          end
        end
```

i have tried clever stuff like

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
        # before_create :run_it
        after_initialize :all_present?
        validates :name, presence: true
        validates :email, presence: true

         private

        def all_present?
            if (@email.nil? || @name.nil?) 
                raise ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError.new()
            end
        end
    end
```

but cannot seem to raise these manually...?
what am i doing wrong?
tx all
Ben

Comment: Take a read on this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MissingAttributeError.html

Comment: ... and this: http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActiveRecord/Validations/PresenceValidator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are 2 methods, [`create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create) and [`create!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create-21). The first, `create`

> The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not

Whereas with `create!`:

> Raises a RecordInvalid error if validations fail, unlike Base#create

So, `create` fails silently and doesn't raise any exceptions, but you can still inspect the instance and see that it's a new record and has errors and such, and `create!` fails noisily, by raising the error you are expecting it to raise. In short, your test should be:

```
it "fails to create user unless both are present" do
  expect { User.create!(:name => 'jo bloggs1')}.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Of course. I have some across ! Just not recalled